# Ellipsis character does not display properly in TMemo component

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, tmemo

A client is reporting an issue whereby she is copying from an e-mail into a screen in a program we have created with Delphi 5. The component on this screen to which she is copying is a TMemo component.

When a line of text contains an ellipsis (...) character or closing quotation marks character ("), the text is replaced with a vertical bar. If the text has two periods in a row, the periods appear correctly. When using the single quotation mark ('), the text appears correctly.

In testing this, I was able to replicate this issue from within an Outlook client and Word document.  The error does not occur when copying text from within Notepad.  The error also does not occur if I create the text from within the TMemo component, copy it into Outlook or Word, then copy it back into the component.

Comment: Upgrade to Unicode Delphi.

Answer (score 4):

You are using Delphi 5 which is an ANSI version of Delphi. The characters that you are trying to copy do not exist in the ANSI character set that your client is using. There is no solution to this problem so long as you persist with ANSI controls. Your options:

1. Switch to a modern version of Delphi that supports Unicode, or
2. Use TNT Unicode controls with your legacy Delphi.